# objective c - NSTableView Reload Data

Tags: objective-c, macos, tableview, nstableview, osx-snow-leopard

I'm developing an application, which works with tableview. I need to load VERY HUGE amount of data into my table view (up to 500k elements). When i load data, i show animation on another view. Animation runs in main thread. Loading data is on background thread. And i perform reload data in table view on background thread too. But i want to make it possible to cancel this operation.

And what i noticed is that fetching up my data lasts for several seconds while loading this data into table view can take up to minute. So, my question is: is there any way to interrupt loading data into table view? I've read tableview programming guide in documentation, but didn't found anything about such things there.

My target SDK is 10.6. I use cell-based tableview

Comment: When you say that you're loading data into the table, what do you mean exactly? Can you show us your code?

Comment: i mean  `[tableView reloadData]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution, that suits me. So, what i did was adding a category to NSTableView with one property: lastRowVisible. I've overrode it's getter in such a way:

```
- (BOOL)isLastRowVisible
{
    NSRect bounds = self.superview.bounds;
    bounds.origin.y += bounds.size.height - 1;
    NSInteger index = [self rowAtPoint:bounds.origin];
    return index == ([self.dataSource numberOfRowsInTableView:self] - 1);
}
```

In my viewController i've added some properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) NSInteger pageNumber;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) NSInteger pageLimit;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) BOOL canLoadMoreData;
```

When I need loading data into tableView i do such a manipulation:

```
self.pageLimit = kDefaultPageLimit;
self.pageNumber = kDefaultPageNumber;

NSInteger visibleNumberOfRows = (self.pageNumber + 1) * self.pageLimit;
self.myDataArray = DataArray;
self.canLoadMoreData = (self.myDataArray.count < visibleNumberOfRows);

[self.myTableView reloadData];
[self.myTableView scrollRowToVisible:0];
```

And in my delegate methods i just check whether i need to load more data or not:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return self.myData.count < self.visibleNumberOfRows ? self.myData.count : self.visibleNumberOfRows;
}

- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{   
    if (tableView.lastRowVisible && self.canLoadMoreData)
    {
        self.pageNumber ++;
        if (self.myData.count < self.visibleNumberOfRows)
        {
            self.canLoadMoreData = NO;
        }
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
    // configure and return cell
}
```

Such a solution works fine for me and suits all my needs.

Comment: `reloadData` inside `dataCellForTableColumn` can't be right. Use `NSTableViewDataSource` methods for data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use load more functionality with page limit and page offset value.
for example you send the page limit 20 in your parameter and page offset will be 0.
Then there are 20 data load in the table view.
Add the load more functionality.when a user scroll down or scroll up above the 20 data then it will call.
Then the page offset will be increase to 1 and the page limit will be 20 to 40.